# add a putSerializable to onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, serialization

i was wondering : the "output" parameter is sent to the superclass, but we add "putSerializable" to it just after that : doesn't it matter that we "modify" it just after we call the superclass? how the app will know that we added this `serializable` if the project is refreshed? (why don't we put the serializable first, and then we call the superclass?)

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }
```

and our onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null : (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either.

The outState is passed to the super by reference therefore any changes afterwards still affect the object.

It's best explained here:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html